# What is the name of this content-addressing scheme?

Tags: terminology

Git seems to use the two most significant hex digits of a content hash as a directory name for content-addressable objects. The same two digits are left out of normal file names. I'm assuming the intent is to limit the size of directory listings, while maintaining a relationship between names and content.

```
objects
├── 01
│   └── db1550e888941883a96b63394f0fe65e892635
├── 02
│   └── 98cc41b182fca79597e9c3fa3fa033eb2673f1
├── 03
│   ├── aa0112ac4942a3f9c64cb6358a7319273e7a33
│   ├── af3aeb71ea5f86af5296f0825c15677c5923ad
│   └── ccc7640a6a7479b2cf566ba14ff4dc7fe773a9
├── 04
│   └── 5e0398efb428a5cfbaa9b65eaca82201638146
...
```

Does this pattern for content-addressable storage have a name independent of the hash function used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) that is truncated to two levels.

Comment: Thank you for this.